# Installing CUDA Toolkit (11.5) on Debian (11)

Tags: debian, apt, nvidia, debian-installer, cuda

The instructions to install CUDA Toolkit (11.5) on Debian (11) are nicely organized here: [developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=11&target_type=deb_network).

But I seem to run in a small dependency issue, whether I try the deb (local) method or deb (network) method. My impression is that `apt` wants to install the `470` versions of nvidia related packages, whereas it should install the `495` versions.

If I run `sudo apt install cuda` then I obtain:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-495 : Depends: nvidia-driver (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcuda1 (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libnvcuvid1 (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libnvidia-allocator1 (>= 495.29.05) but 470.74-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libnvidia-compiler (>= 495.29.05) but 470.74-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libnvidia-encode1 (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libnvidia-fbc1 (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libnvidia-opticalflow1 (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler1 (>= 495.29.05) but 470.74-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libnvoptix1 (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxnvctrl-dev (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-cuda-mps (>= 495.29.05) but 470.74-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-detect (>= 495.29.05) but 470.74-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-libopencl1 (>= 495.29.05) but 470.74-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-opencl-common (>= 495.29.05)
                    Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-smi (>= 495.29.05) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-xconfig (>= 495.29.05) but 470.57.02-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-modprobe (>= 495.29.05)
 libcufile-11-5 : Depends: liburcu6 but it is not installable
 nvidia-libopencl1 : Conflicts: libopencl1
                     Conflicts: libopencl1:i386
                     Recommends: nvidia-opencl-icd but it is not going to be installed or
                                 opencl-icd
 ocl-icd-libopencl1 : Conflicts: libopencl1
 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 : Conflicts: libopencl1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I managed to install some dependencies by specifying the version manually, e.g. `sudo apt install nvidia-settings=495.29.05-1` but this seems like an endless process.

Note: If I run `sudo apt-cache policy nvidia-driver` then I obtain:

```
nvidia-driver:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 470.74-1
  Version table:
     495.29.05-1 500
        500 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian11/x86_64  Packages
        500 file:/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-5-local  Packages
     470.74-1 990
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/non-free amd64 Packages
```

Does anyone know how I should proceed?

At the moment my /etc/apt/sources.list is as follows:

```
deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian11/x86_64/ /
# deb-src https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian11/x86_64/ /
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
```

PS: I also tried the "runfile (local)" method, but after running `sudo sh cuda_11.5.0_495.29.05_linux.run` and selecting the components to install, I get "Installation failed" with no further details.

Comment: before running this cuda install first remove all nvidia packages once done assure this shows nothing :  `dpkg -l|grep nvidia` ... remove anything which shows from that command ... also remove all files from dir `/var/crash` then reboot you will now be using nouveau driver then run above cuda install ... keep in mind by installing cuda it will automatically install its matching nvidia driver version ... also this is less error prone when run when on one of the LTS releases of the OS

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on Debian 12 (testing).  I fixed it by downloading the .deb for liburcu6 from
https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/liburcu6
and installing it with

```
sudo apt install ./Downloads/liburcu6_0.12.2-1_amd64.deb
```

After that, re-running `sudo apt-get -y install cuda` worked fine.  Didn't dive more deeply to see why newer Debian versions aren't including liburcu6 in them.

Comment: This has worked for me as well on a Debian Testing! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Exit `xserver` before you run the install so that the `nvidia-driver` install does not fail.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but with the recent release 510.39.01 and cuda 11-6;

```
/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-6-local# dpkg -i nvidia-libopencl1_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-libopencl1:amd64.
dpkg: regarding nvidia-libopencl1_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb containing nvidia-libopencl1:amd64:
 nvidia-libopencl1 conflicts with libopencl1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 provides libopencl1 and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive nvidia-libopencl1_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing nvidia-libopencl1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-libopencl1_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
```

```
# dpkg -l | grep liburcu6
ii  liburcu6:amd64                         0.12.2-1                           amd64        userspace RCU (read-copy-update) library
```

Course if I try to remove `ocl-icd-libopencl1`, I have about 50 packages that depend on it. I think Vincent had already worked on this bug debian #755513, but that might be a new issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/401553)

Answer (score 0):

> I fixed it by downloading the .deb for liburcu6 from https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/liburcu6 and installing it with
>
> ```
> sudo apt install ./Downloads/liburcu6_0.12.2-1_amd64.deb
> ```

I visited the page mentioned, but only the following architectures are listed:

```
Architecture    Package Size    Installed Size    Files
amd64           69.7 kB         366.0 kB          [list of files]
arm64           67.9 kB         342.0 kB          [list of files]
armel           62.7 kB         316.0 kB          [list of files]
armhf           63.1 kB         248.0 kB          [list of files]
i386            69.8 kB         348.0 kB          [list of files]
mips64el        62.0 kB         341.0 kB          [list of files]
mipsel          62.2 kB         326.0 kB          [list of files]
ppc64el         72.0 kB         610.0 kB          [list of files]
s390x           67.2 kB         342.0 kB          [list of files]
```

I need one for amd64 (Intel CPUs also use this architecture). 
What can I do?

Comment: Please don’t post a new answer just to say that another answer didn’t work for you. But … what is your problem? The page includes “amd64”, as shown in your quote.